# CSS Styling in XML file

Tags: html, css, .net, xml, email

Below code is under xml file, which contains email contents. I want to add background color and font style in #surveyName. Help me to do

```
 <Body>
      &lt;html&gt;
      &lt;body&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;
      #SurveyName
      &lt;/p&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;
      We are Conducting a survey and your input would be appreciated. &lt;a href="#SurveyURL"&gt;Click Here &lt;/a&gt; to Start the survey.Thank you for your Participation.
      &lt;/p&gt;
      &lt;br&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;
     Please do not forward this email as its survey link is unique to you.
      &lt;/p&gt;
      &lt;br&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;
      Powered by Survey Management System.
      &lt;/p&gt;
      &lt;/body&gt;
      &lt;/html&gt;
    </Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.

This anser might be of use to you as it encodes htmlspecialchars in #c
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16802/1105422

```
var encodedHtml = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode("<a href=\"http://example.com\" style=\"background-color:red\">Click Here to Start the survey.</a>")
```

Comment: Sorry, my first example was for PHP. I have edited my answer.